# Local Notification erro ao clicar instacia novamente o mesmo app

Tags: java, android

Seguinte, eu criei um app de rádio e quando o app abre tem a splash e começa tocar. Tem um funcionalidade de agendar um programa. Se eu estiver com o app aberto e chegar a notificação, ele continua tocando a rádio, inicia novamente e fica com 2 audios da radio, preciso que quando eu clique na notificação o app finalize para que possa abrir novamente e tocar. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Tenho várias ideias, o problema é que não tenho a mínima ideia de como está estruturada a sua aplicação.

Comment: Me da umas ideias de o que acha que poderia ser para eu ter um norte, porque já testei de tudo e não consegui solucionar esse problema.

Comment: Quando clica na notificação é aberta outra Activity? Ou seja, ficam duas Activities iguais abertas?